# Running Gradle Build - Failed When i tried to run ionic capacitor run android -l --external

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor, livereload

so before i just changed my device, my ionic project working just fine when i tried to run live reload. i think i have installed all the same version of jdk and node js as my old device.

and now, i've been getting this error when i tried to run ionic cap run android -l --external

```
[capacitor] × Running Gradle build - failed!
[capacitor] [error]
[capacitor]         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
[capacitor]         > Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
 [in thread "Daemon worker"]
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Try:
[capacitor]         Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run wi
th --scan to get full insights.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         BUILD FAILED in 1s
[capacitor]
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

i've been looking for answers, and mostly they told me to change this line of code

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

but it just gave me another error. i tried to change it to some other versions. but still, it didnt work.

I expected my ionic app will be able to run livereload.

Comment: Try to run it with --debug option , maybe it gives you more insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding this line in my gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).